# SublimePaneNavigation Plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I found this plugint SublimePaneNavigation, and from the fitures it looks great but it's suppouse to be only for sublime 2, I cant find it on sublime 3 package control. Can I install it some other way, on a Sublime text 3?

[SublimePaneNavigation](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Pane%20Navigation)

[SublimePanelNavigation](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Pane%20Navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell this plugin should work in ST3, but you'll have to install it yourself to find out. Go to your `Packages` directory (select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to find it) via the command line, and (assuming you have `git` installed) run the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/borist/SublimePaneNavigation.git
```

It should then be installed.